# Cleaning cat saliva/hair out of used furniture: how effective is it?

Tags: cats, cleaning, allergies

We just were presented with a pretty good opportunity to buy a good couch on the second-hand market that would fit our space pretty well. We like it, but the fly in the ointment is that for a six month period, there was a cat in the home, and I have pretty terrible cat allergies. We went over to look at it and after sitting on the couch for a few minutes, I had some mild symptoms crop up during our drive home.

I know that we could wet-clean the couch to some degree, but I'm most curious how effective doing something like that is, especially for the more sensitive? I don't want to pass up this deal if cleaning is reasonably effective (I know nothing can be 100% guaranteed), but I also don't want to play with proverbial fire.

Any recommendations are welcome!

Comment: As a minimum, please tell us what materials were used in the making of that couch. Sponge beneath probably? What is on the top? Fabric, natural leather, plastic-leather... Was the couch ever wet-cleaned? If yes, the allergens might have gotten inside - so surface cleaning will help as much as massaging a wooden leg.